# How to get default selected value in ngx-select in Angular 4 & above?

Tags: angular, typescript, select

I am trying to implement searchable select box where data is coming from an API. I have displayed that data using for loop & search is working fine. I need to now set by default value for the same & also I am using Reactive Forms.

This is the HTML Part :

```
<ngx-select [formControl]="selectedUserId" 
                      [allowClear]="true"
                      [items]="userData"
                      placeholder="Select User ID"
                      >
        </ngx-select>
```

This is the TS Part :

```
constructor(private http: HttpService, private fb: FormBuilder, public usr?: UserService, public datepipe?: DatePipe) {
    this.http.getMethod('User/masterpasswordchange').subscribe((data: any) => {
      const items1: Array<any> = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        items1.push(data[i].userid);
      }
      this.userData = items1;
      this.atAdminName = this.fb.group({
        fromDate: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
        toDate: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
        selectedUserId: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      })
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys the working solution is below

```
 constructor(private http: HttpService, private fb: FormBuilder, public usr?: UserService, public datepipe?: DatePipe) {
    this.fetchdata();
  }

  formFunction(data) {
    this.atAdminName = this.fb.group({
      fromDate: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
      toDate: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
      selectedUserId: new FormControl(data[3], Validators.required)
    });
  }

  fetchdata() {
    this.http.getMethod('User/masterpasswordchange').subscribe((data: any) => {
      const items1: Array<any> = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        items1.push(data[i].userid);
      }
      this.userData = items1;
      console.log(this.userData);
      this.formFunction(this.userData);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

add `formControlName` attribute to the select.

```
<ngx-select formControlName="selectedUserId" [allowClear]="true" [items]="userData" placeholder="Select User ID">
</ngx-select>
```

Now set the default value.

```
this.atAdminName .controls['selectedUserId'].setValue('yourValue', {onlySelf: true});
```

Comment: [formGroup] is already defined once as I have 4 fields rest are input boxes.

Comment: OK let me quickly check out the above code give me 5 minz i will be back to you

Comment: No brother this didnt worked from me. where should i define this - >this.atAdminName .controls['selectedUserId'].setValue('yourValue', {onlySelf: true});

Comment: Inside constructor. After form group definition